# Android Xamarin fingerprint get unique id to set username

Tags: xamarin, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api

I am new to xamarin.

In my first project I will just create a fingerprint login and say hello to the logged-in user:

So in android I have 3 fingerprints:

```
user1 = **alex**
user2 = **steven**
user3 = **sam**
```

for now iam using this [fingerprint plugin](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint)

is it possible to get an unique id which fingerprint is used?

so if alex put his finger on the sensor I get as a result a unique id = 123456789 (every time user alex put his finger on the sensor)

at the end i will output the current authentcated user like **hi alex**
or is it possible with another plugin/code?

thanks

Comment: Unique fingerprint values are not available, the biometric (fingerprint, face, palm, ...) is linked to a singular user account along with any other security attributes defined (pin, swipe, nfc key, etc...)

Comment: ah okay , So i must create a user account for every user... thanks